# unable to create a foreign key constraint

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a clients, feedback and a repairs tables. A client can give many feedbacks and have many repairs. In the feedback table I have created a clientid column (added also index) and I am able to create a foreign key to the clientid column (primary key) of the clients table.

The problem is that I am unable to do the same with the repairs table. Even though I have created a clientid column (indexed) within the repairs table and it has the same properties as the clientid within the clients table I get the following:

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint
>   fails (`ccsdb`.,
>   CONSTRAINT `#sql-3f0_8e5_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`client_id`) REFERENCES
>   `clients` (`client_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error (`Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails`) is referenced in the [MySQL FK Doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

To add a reference between 2 tables the condition must fit for existing data.

That means if you say `table1.id = table2.id` then all ids of `table1` and `table2` must match together.

To solve that you have to eliminate or fix those rows that don't match. 
Example:

```
table1.id  |  table2.fk
   1       |       1      ok 
   2       |     null     error
   3       |       4      error if id 4 is not in table1
```

Comment: absolutely right mate, I removed entres in the repair table that had their clientid reference not matching the clientid within the clients table and it let me create the foreign key. Many thanks.